# C++ linux debug trace not coming out

Tags: c++, linux, output

The code below runs on windows ok and the trace but after transferring and building it on linux nothing comes out on the window. Here is the program (I've literally commented everything out after the trace output now):

```
int main(int argc, char const* const argv[])
{
     std::cerr << "Hello" << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

I kick the program off and nothing comes out. It builds without error on linux (and windows). The trace comes out in windows but I get nothing in linux.

Comment: what are `Global::programDescription` and `InputError`??????

Comment: Global::programDescription is just a string. Input error is this (sry about formmating in this box): class InputError //Exception
{
private:
 std::string text;

public:
 InputError(char const myText[])
  : text(myText)
 {}
 InputError(std::string const& myText)
  : text(myText)
 {}
 InputError(std::stringstream const& myText)
  : text(myText.str())
 {}

 std::string const& Text() const {return text;}
};

Comment: The code you posted is not valid C++.  Please make sure your code is copy-pastable into a compiler and edit your question.  Often, you will answer your own question trying to produce a minimally compilable example.

Comment: Please show the _complete_ test case. This code does not compile.

Comment: Also, please show how you compile and run it.

Comment: The latest version of your program does compile and prints "Hello" as expected.

Comment: ok, if I build it with g++ it works as expected. If I build it with my makefile it doesn't work. The 'make' doesnt bomb out and builds the executable as epxected. But the executable doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is a makefile issue. If I compile the program using g++ it works. If I use the makefile it doesn't work although it says it has built and linked without error.